# Increase admob revenue using filters

Tags: android, admob, ads, adwhirl

I have android application with about 1 Million downloads and most of my application users are located in the Middle East. Before two weeks the downloads were 200K and the revenue was reasonable and CPM was $0.15 (yes it is Low CPM), ads requests were about 500K.

Now after reaching 1 Million downloads the CPM is $0.04 and the revenue is less than before, and Ads requests now are 1.5 million.

All the time during my app life time, the fill rate is more that 99%.

I have many thoughts about this drop in CPM:
* Old inventory (before two weeks) was higher in price compared to current campaigns.

In all cases, it is very low and I'm feeling very bad.

I started to think about using filters to get more profitable ads even if the fill rate is went down.

My question is: 
1- What tips do you know to filter out cheap Ads? 
2- What Ads Category/Type are better to enable in admob filter settings? 
Note: I mean by types something like: Communications, E-commerce, Games, (Movies, TV, and Entertainment), etc...

Comment: This question should be reopened. This question needs to be geared toward on how to use the AbMob online software - usage of the filters.